# I can't get out from ctrl+alt+f3

Tags: virtualbox

I have a little problem, I can't get out from Ctrl+Alt+F3. I tryed with Ctrl+Alt+F7 but nothing happend. Can you help me please?

Comment: Try other function keys. I assume you are working in a VM, so it is not clear which session is the graphical one. (could be anything between F3 and F10)

Comment: Alright, im gonna try. :D

Comment: I tryed , it doesn't work...

Comment: Had similar problems during logout and login. Have you got "GuestAdditions" installed (assuming you are using VirtualBox) - I would be great if you could describe the exact setup in your question (which host, which VM, which Addons, which Ubuntu etc). Easier for everyone (hence **not** in the comments)